# Error :'error TS2339: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Response'.- Angular

Tags: angular, charts, highcharts, angular6

I'm a newbie in learning Angular 6, I'm getting below errors when I execute below code. Kindly anyone helpme to resolve this issue.

I'm getting below error in the browser console and find files below for your reference.
Error:

```
Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for AppComponent: (?).
at syntaxError (compiler.js:1016)
at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (compiler.js:10917)
at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (compiler.js:10810)
at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver.getNonNormalizedDirectiveMetadata (compiler.js:10429)
at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver._getEntryComponentMetadata (compiler.js:11013)
at compiler.js:10673
at Array.map (<anonymous>)
at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (compiler.js:10673)
at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._loadModules (compiler.js:23846)
at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:23827)
```

Below is app component file

app.Component.ts

```
        import { Component, Input, OnInit, OnDestroy  } from '@angular/core';
        import { Subscription,Observable } from 'rxjs';
        import { AppService } from './app.service';
        import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
        import { Chart } from 'angular-highcharts';
        import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
        @Component({
          selector: 'app-root',
          templateUrl: './app.component.html',
          styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
        })
        export class AppComponent implements OnDestroy, OnInit  {
          title = 'my-project';
           @Input() showMePartially: boolean;
            options: any;
            data: number;
            chart: any;
            dataSubscription: Subscription;
            chartData$ : Object;
            constructor(public appService: AppService) {
               this.options = {
                chart: {  type: 'pie',
                         plotBackgroundColor: null,
                        plotBorderWidth: null,
                        plotShadow: false,  },
           //     legend: { enabled: false },
                credits: { enabled: false },
                 tooltip: {
       //     pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: false,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false,
             //      format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                }
              }
            },
                 series: [{
                  name: 'Dispo',
                  data: []
                }]
            };
        }

       // onPointSelect (e) {
         // this.point = e.context.y;
       // }

       saveInstance(chartInstance) {
        this.chart = chartInstance;
      //   console.log(chartInstance);
    }
     public ngOnInit () {
        this.dataSubscription = this.appService.getData().subscribe((data) => {
         69 LINE - this.options.series[0].data = data.data.operating_rate;
           // Code for the pie

            let percentUp = data.data.operating_rate; // 88.14
            let percentDown = 100 - percentUp; // 11.86
            this.options.series[0].data = [
            {
            name: 'Up',
            y: percentUp,
            color: 'green'
            },
            {
            name: 'Down',
            y: percentDown,
            color: 'white'
            }
            ]
          console.log(data);
       });
    }
        public ngOnDestroy() {
          if (this.dataSubscription) {
    this.dataSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
   }
}
```

Below is app Component file
app.Component.html

```
<chart [options]="options">
      <series>
     </series>
  </chart>
```

app.Service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import { timer } from 'rxjs/observable/timer';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/timer';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/publishBehavior';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

@Injectable()
export class AppService {

  data: any;
  appService: Observable<AppService[]>;

  constructor(public http: Http) { }

  getData(){
        /*const tick3 = Observable.timer(100, 60000); 
  this.appService = tick3.flatMap(() => http.get(usersURL)).map(res => [res.json()]).publishBehavior(<AppService[]>[]).refCount();*/
        return this.http.get('https://my-json-server.typicode.com/techsithgit/json-faker-directory/profiles');

    }
 }
const usersURL = 'https://my-json-server.typicode.com/techsithgit/json-faker-directory/profiles';
```

app.module.ts

```
 import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { NgModule,CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA  } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { ChartModule } from 'angular-highcharts';
    import * as highcharts from 'highcharts';


    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent

      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpModule,
        ChartModule

      ],
      providers: [],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent],
      schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

console error

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'options' since it isn't a known property of 'chart'. ("<!--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
<chart [ERROR ->][options]="options">
      <series>
     </series>
"): ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@1:7
'series' is not a known element:
1. If 'series' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
<chart [options]="options">
      [ERROR ->]<series>
     </series>
  </chart>
"): ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@2:6
'chart' is not a known element:
1. If 'chart' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("<!--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
[ERROR ->]<chart [options]="options">
      <series>
     </series>
"): ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@1:0
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:1016)
    at TemplateParser.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.TemplateParser.parse (compiler.js:14813)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._parseTemplate (compiler.js:23988)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileTemplate (compiler.js:23975)
    at compiler.js:23918
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.js:23918)
    at compiler.js:23828
    at Object.then (compiler.js:1007)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:23827)
```

Comment: which line throws the data error?

Comment: @fireGloves line 27 ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(69,42): error TS2339: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Response'.

Comment: can you put a sign in your code here? I have no line number on stackoverflow :) and please post your json response

Comment: @firegloves I have added the line number in app.component.ts file Line 69 please check and im getting the error instead of json response kindly find it in above question with the tag line console error

Comment: i think your problem is this code: data.data  .please post your json response data to see what it contains

Comment: hi firegloves i have added the error .Please find it in above section

Comment: i don't know the library you are using, but you have an error in parsing <series> html tag

Comment: Im using highcharts ,and im getting data ,below is my json response:"operating_details":[[1497837618,0],[1497837738,0],[1497837858,0],
  [1497837978,0],[1497838098,0],[1497838218,0],[1497838338,0],
  [1497838458,0],[1497838578,0],[1497838698,0],[1497838818,0],
  [1497838938,0],[1497839058,0],[1497839178,0],[1497839298,0],
  [1497839418,0],[1497839538,0],[1497839658,0],[1497839778,0]]   its from res.json file and https://my-json-server.typicode.com/techsithgit/json-faker-directory/profiles

Comment: I can't find into highcharts documentation a reference to <series> tag

Comment: Actually i have commented out the part where res.json is referred in app.service file and used  my-json-server.typicode.com/techsithgit/json-faker-directory/ for time being

Comment: @firegloves you can find here https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/series

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried adding `Inject` directive to your `app.component.ts` file? Here is the code of component constructor:

```
constructor(@Inject(AppService) public appService: AppService)
```

app.component.ts file changes :

```
export class AppComponent implements OnDestroy, OnInit {
  title = 'my-project';
  @Input() showMePartially: boolean;
  options: any;
  data: number;
  chart: any;
  dataSubscription: Subscription;
  chartData$: Object;
  constructor(@Inject(AppService) public appService: AppService) {
    this.options = {
      chart: {
        type: 'pie',
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: null,
        plotShadow: false,
      },
      //     legend: { enabled: false },
      credits: {
        enabled: false
      },
      tooltip: {
        //     pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
      },
      plotOptions: {
        pie: {
          allowPointSelect: false,
          cursor: 'pointer',
          dataLabels: {
            enabled: false,
            //      format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
          }
        }
      },
      series: [{
        name: 'Dispo',
        data: []
      }]
    };
  }
```

Don't forget about importing appropriate directive:

```
 import { Component, Input, Inject, OnInit, OnDestroy  } from '@angular/core';
```

Comment: im trying it now,will let you know once its completed

Comment: Hi Daniel im getting below error ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(67,45): error TS2339: Property 'subscribe' doe
s not exist on type 'AppService'. at line   this.dataSubscription = this.appService.subscribe((data)

Comment: It occurs because you didn't defined the `subscribe()` function in your app.service, but it's other question. My answer resolves your problem, so please mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

As you have coded into AppService:

```
getData: any;
```

By this way you are only declaring a variable. To invoke a `getData` function you should have something like this into AppService:

```
getData(): void {
   // DO SOMETHING
}
```

Comment: Hi Firegloves I have tried it but got above error.I have updated the question